# Pyspark: Using UDF with argument(s) to create a new column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a user defined function as follows which I want to use to derive new columns in my dataframe:

```
def to_date_formatted(date_str, format):
    if date_str == '' or date_str is None:
        return None
    try:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, format)
    except:
        return None
    return dt.date()

spark.udf.register("to_date_udf", to_date_formatted, DateType())
```

I can use this by running sql like `select to_date_udf(my_date, '%d-%b-%y') as date`.  Note the ability to pass a custom format as an argument to the function

However, I'm struggling to use it using pyspark column expression syntax, rather than sql

I want to write something like:

```
df.with_column("date", to_date_udf('my_date', %d-%b-%y')
```

But this results in an error.  How can I do this?

[Edit:  In this specific example, in Spark 2.2+ you can provide an optional format argument with the built in `to_date` function.  I'm on Spark 2.0 at the moment, so this is not possible for me.  Also worth noting I provided this as an example, but I'm interested in the general syntax for providing arguments to UDFs, rather than the specifics of date conversion]

Comment: Thank you - the answer to that question is useful and confirms my findings. 
 I spent a of time Google trying to find an answer for this one, but I was searching more broadly for thing like 'pyspark udf arguments', and the title of that other question only indirectly relates to this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have found three options for achieving this:

#### Setup reproducible example

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime 

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, lit

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc) 

def to_date_formatted(date_str, format):
    if date_str == '' or date_str is None:
        return None
    try:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, format)
    except:
        return None
    return dt.date()

data = {}
data["date_str_1"] = ["01-Dec-17", "05-Jan-12", "08-Mar-15"]
data["date_str_2"] = ["01/12/17", "05/01/12", "08/03/15"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
df.registerTempTable('df')
```

#### Option 1

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
to_date_udf = udf(to_date_formatted, DateType())
df = df.withColumn("parsed_date", to_date_udf('date_str_1', lit('%d-%b-%y')))
df.show()
```

#### Option 2

```
spark.udf.register("to_date_udf", to_date_formatted, DateType())
ex = "to_date_udf(date_str_1, '%d-%b-%y') as d"
df = df.withColumn("parsed_date", expr(ex))

df.show()
```

#### Option 3

Option 3 is just to curry the `to_date_formatted` function:

```
from functools import partial
curried_to_date = partial(to_date_formatted, format="%d-%b-%y")

curried_to_date = udf(curried_to_date, DateType())
df.withColumn("parsed_date", curried_to_date('date_str_1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=to_date#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date

df.withColumn("date_str_1_", to_date("date_str_1", "dd-MMM-yy")).show()
# +----------+----------+-----------+
# |date_str_1|date_str_2|date_str_1_|
# +----------+----------+-----------+
# | 01-Dec-17|  01/12/17| 2017-12-01|
# | 05-Jan-12|  05/01/12| 2012-01-05|
# | 08-Mar-15|  08/03/15| 2015-03-08|
# +----------+----------+-----------+

df.withColumn("date_str_2_", to_date("date_str_2", "dd/MM/yy")).show()
# +----------+----------+-----------+
# |date_str_1|date_str_2|date_str_2_|
# +----------+----------+-----------+
# | 01-Dec-17|  01/12/17| 2017-12-01|
# | 05-Jan-12|  05/01/12| 2012-01-05|
# | 08-Mar-15|  08/03/15| 2015-03-08|
# +----------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm on Spark 2.0, and unfortunately to_date didn't take a date formater until Spark 2.2 - until then, the string had to be in iso format

Comment: With earlier version https://stackoverflow.com/q/45492203/8371915